# CS50 Pset4 filter-more blur() function not working

Tags: c, image, image-processing, cs50

Link to the problem (blur part only) [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/more/).

In this code I am trying to blur a bmp image by taking the weighted sum across 3x3 matrix for each pixel and replacing the original value with the average obtained.

I have tried various different things, the code compiles correctly (there is no error), and also I couldn't find any problem while debugging the code , but the output image obtained is not what was desired, it is a black and colored pattern repeated 3 times vertically instead of the edges of the input photo.

Thanks for helping out.

Here is the main code of the function:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Array for storing corresponding blur values of the pixels.
    RGBTRIPLE(*blur)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store blur pixels.\n");
        return;
    }


    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            sum3x3(row, col, height, width, image, blur);
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            image[row][col] = blur[row][col];
        }
    }


    free(blur);
    return;
}
```

Here is the code for sum3x3 function:

```
void sum3x3(int row, int col, int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE matrix[row][col], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[row][col] )
{
    float counter = 0;
    float blue = 0;
    float green = 0;
    float red = 0;

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
        {
            // skip rows out of range.
            if ( (i + row) < 0 || (i + row >= height)) continue;
            // skip columns out of range.
            if ( (j + col) < 0 || (j + col >= width)) continue;
            // add to sum.

            counter ++;

            blue += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtBlue;
            green += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtGreen;
            red += matrix[i + row][j + col].rgbtRed;

        }
    }

    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtBlue += round(blue/counter);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtGreen += round(green/counter);
    new_matrix[row][col].rgbtRed += round(red/counter);
}
```

The RGBTRIPLE data structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Update: I made some changes to the code according to the suggestions in comments but still not getting the desired output.

Comment: The `rgbtBlue/9` is doing *integer division*.

Comment: The parameters of the `sum3x3()` function should end with `RGBTRIPLE matrix[height][width], RGBTRIPLE new_matrix[height][width]`, surely?

Comment: You divide `/9` for each pixel, even if you only add up 4 pixel in a corner. You must count the number of pixels you summed up and divide afterwards. Then use floating point division and round the result before storing in the resultint image.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to copy the `struct` members individually. You can do `image[row][col] = blur[row][col];`

Comment: @WeatherVane I made both the changes but the result is still the same vague output

Comment: @Gerhardh But if a don't divide before adding then , it may reach the max limit of the 8 bit unsigned integer(BYTE) to store the values, also if we once neglect corner pixels , then also the rest of the image should seem correct, which is not the case.

Comment: @r3mainer I didn't quite get you , can you please elaborate ?

Comment: The `float` isn't max 8 bit. Sum the byte values into a `float`, count the number of pixels too, and divide the `float` sum by the pixels counted (not by 9).

Comment: and *then* assign to the new pixel value.

Comment: If you think you might get an overflow, just chose a larger data type for calculating intermediate values. Only afterwards scale down again to fit into destination type. There is no need to sum up all the parts in the desination array. You can just use an extra set of 3 floats to sum up each color. Then you are not limited to range of your destination type.

Comment: @nishkant Your definition of this function states that it should be passed an array of `row` rows and `col` columns. And then you try to access the element at `[row+1][col+1]`, which clearly doesn't exist. As a result, you're fetching data from completely the wrong place.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made the changes suggested by you but still the output is not obtained :)

Comment: @Gerhardh I made the changes suggested by you but still the output is not obtained :)

Comment: You did not change according to Weather Vane's comment. You still claim that the arrays passed to your function have `row` rows and `col` columns. That is still wrong. Use `height` and `width` as dimensions of the array. If you specify wrong dimensions, all the address calculations in the function will be wrong.

Comment: What is the desired output? What is the actual output? Run with a very small input (something like 4x4) and show where exactly is the discrepancy.

Comment: @Gerhardh I made those changes and got the output correct this time, such a silly mistake , due to which it took 15 days to solve this problem., still stuck on the edge detection function , Thank you btw

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane the problem is resolved

Comment: Thanks @r3mainer the problem is resolved